# using R - passing rows from 2 data.frames using purrr::map to calculate a result using values from both data.frames

Tags: r, loops, purrr

I have 2 data.frames that store values that will be retrieved and used in an equation.  I would like to calculate the result for each row in df1 using each row in df2... basically iterating through the first df rows with each row of the second df.

```
df1 <- tibble(Type=c("atype","btype","ctype"),
              h=c("1","2","3"),
              w=c("4","5","6"),
              ED=c("101","102","103"))

df2 <- tibble(Item=c("123-htc","but-456","xtc","newID"),
              limit=c("rnorm(1)","12","13","14"),
              zone=c("30","40","30","11"))
#Note: values in dfs stored as characters/strings to also use get values from random number functions

resItm <- list()
resTyp <- list()


for (i in 1:length(df1$Type)) {
   h <- NULL
   w <- NULL
   ED <- NULL
   limit <- NULL
   zone <- NULL
   for (j in 1:length(df2$Item)) {
      Typ<-df1[i,]
      Itm<-df2[j,]
      h<-eval(str2lang(Typ$h))
      w<-eval(str2lang(Typ$w))
      ED<-eval(str2lang(Typ$ED))
      limit<-eval(str2lang(Itm$limit))
      zone<-eval(str2lang(Itm$zone))
      
      res1 <- (h * limit * ED) / (zone)
      
      resItm[[j]] <- list(Item=Itm$Item, Result=res1)
   }
   resTyp[[i]] <- list(Type=Typ$Type, Res_Item = resItm)
}

str(resTyp)
```

This worked fine with nested `for` loops and got me to the expected results, however, I was trying to also do this with purrr::map.  And thats when it didn't work so well

```
map2(df1,df2,function(.x,.y) {(eval(str2lang(.x$h))*eval(str2lang(.y$limit))*eval(str2lang(.x$ED)))/eval(str2lang(.y$zone))})

#Error in `map2()`:
#! Can't recycle `.x` (size 4) to match `.y` (size 3).
#Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

How the heck do I get this to work... i also tried nested map() calls, and tried putting the calculation in a named function `map(df1,~map(df2,~c(...)))` but that doesnt let me get at the values in each column...

Surely passing 2 dfs row wise to a function has been tried before where each row in one df is iterated with the other??  any help appreciated!

Comment: If you meant to loop over rows, use `map` with sequence of rows instead of `map2`, as `map2` is comparing the corresponding columns `map(seq_len(nrow(df1)), ~ )`

Comment: Also, not clear why you are using `str2lang` and `eval`.  If the column types are different, wouldn't it be easier to use `type.convert` on the entire data  i.e. `df1 <- type.convert(df1, as.is = TRUE)`

Comment: I need to access both dataframes (at the same time) to do the calculation so I can pull values from each row in each of the tables... so not really sure from your example how to implement that @akrun